# ionic cordova build android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to build my ionic 2 project using the command `ionic cordova build android` but I cant successfully build it. Hope you can help me with this problem, Thanks in advance. Here is the error:

```
> cordova build android
```

× Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

```
    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\kiel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Unzipping C:\Users\kiel\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3-all.zip to
    C:\Users\kiel\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1g
```

Comment: Delete `C:\Users\kiel\.gradle` folder

Comment: thank you for the response, can I just ask why should I delete the .gradle folder?

Comment: Because it's causing errors and it will get re-downloaded

Comment: I already deleted it but it still do not build successfully.

Comment: Then change the Gradle version in the properties file

Comment: thank you very much but how can I change the Gradle version?

Comment: There's a `gradle.properties` file somewhere in your Android project folder

Comment: it is gradle-wrapper.properties folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Ant instead of graddle?
Try this command:

```
ionic cordova build android -- --ant
```